# Swing GUI freezes for unknown reason

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm creating a java program that creates lineups for Grand Prix/Pinewood Derby like races and then once scores are entered finds the finalists and assigns them a lane/heat number.

So far everything in the program does exactly what I want it to do until I reach the part where I'm trying to create the finalists. After I click the button/press enter to enter in the final score, my GUI freezes. Here is the code right before the freeze:

```
//allows user to enter the places for each car in each heat in each round
void enterScores() {
    if(indexCount == 0 || (indexCount) % numLanes == 0) {
        textArea.append("\nRound " + (roundCount + 1) + " Heat " + (heatCount+1) + ": ");
    }
    userResponse.setText("");
    prompt.setText(holderNameArray[roundCount][indexCount] + ": ");
    textArea.append("\n" + holderNameArray[roundCount][indexCount] + ": ");
    userResponse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            holderScoreArray[roundCount][indexCount] = Integer.parseInt(userResponse.getText());
            textArea.append("" + holderScoreArray[roundCount][indexCount]);
            indexCount++;
            for(ActionListener act : enter.getActionListeners()) {
                enter.removeActionListener(act);
            }
            for(ActionListener act : userResponse.getActionListeners()) {
                            userResponse.removeActionListener(act);
                        }
            repeatEnterScores();
        }
    });
    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            holderScoreArray[roundCount][indexCount] = Integer.parseInt(userResponse.getText());
            textArea.append("" + holderScoreArray[roundCount][indexCount]);
            indexCount++;
            for(ActionListener act : enter.getActionListeners()) {
                enter.removeActionListener(act);
            }
            for(ActionListener act : userResponse.getActionListeners()) {
                            userResponse.removeActionListener(act);
                        }
            repeatEnterScores();
        }
    });

}
//helps repeat enterScores() due to anon class restrictions
//checks to change the number of heats/rounds
void repeatEnterScores() {
    if((indexCount) % numLanes == 0 || indexCount == numCars) {
        heatCount++;
    }
    if(indexCount == numCars) {
        indexCount = 0;
        heatCount = 0;
        roundCount++;
    }
    if(roundCount < numRounds) {
        enterScores();
    } else {
        textArea.setText("You may now click the Scores tab to see the scores you have just entered.");
        scoresPanelSetup();
    }
}
```

It used to not freeze and continue, but would freeze in a later place instead. I'm a beginner so I'm not sure why it's freezing here now. If you need any more code/information, please let me know. Whenever I debug it steps through all of my code fine, it's just the gui having problems.

Thanks!

Comment: Try debugging and check which line exactly it blocks.

Comment: Is GUI running in its own thread?

Comment: There is a high chance you are doing gui updates not on event dispatch thread.

Comment: Have you checked for infinite loops?

Comment: I definitely had no infinite loops because that was the first thing I checked for. I even edited a loop later in the program just to make sure that wasn't the problem. As far as running in it's own thread...I'm not actually sure how to do that. If that's possibly the problem, does anyone have any links to how I could initiate that?

Comment: enter.removeActionListener(act); == Swing Action.setEnabled(false), for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: It might come from the fact that you are removing ActionListeners while an event is being dispatched.

Comment: You remove actionListeners in one of the actionListeners? I must say, to this time, I only read about such practice and never believed anyone would do that...

Comment: Not to mention the removal of the ActionListener at all. If you don't want an Object to have an ActionListener, why give it one?

Comment: Your code looks completely, um... how to say this tactfully,... "unique" comes to mind. Don't assume that there's no endless loops just yet, don't assume anything until you can isolate and correct your error. For us to give you better help though, you should try to simplify and coalesce your code into a small compilable testable unit, an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: When it is blocked, take a thread dump and see what is happening on the thread named `AWT EventQueue`

Answer (score 1):

GUI can hang if you are trying to do a long operation on EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). You can avoid this by using SwingWorker. SwingWorker has two methods i.e doInBackground() and done(). You should do your computation in doInBackground() method and update the UI in done() method. You can learn more about SwingWorker from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html.